# Scope of Application.OnException AND Delphi

Tags: delphi, exception, initialization, delphi-xe4

I am a new programmer and trying to understand how Delphi's `Application.OnException` event works. A colleague has modified the default exception handling by creating his own method and instantiating it and passing it to `Application.OnException` in the `initialization` section of a unit. This unit is declared in the `uses` clause of another unit and otherwise unused.

```
unit ADLDebug;
...

class procedure TADLExceptionHandler.ADLHandleException (Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
...

initialization
   Handler := TADLExceptionHandler.Create;
   Application.OnException := Handler.ADLHandleException;
```

I can only step into the `initialization` section using the debugger, and not into the `ADLHandleException` method. I am trying to cause an exception in the code that will be caught by the redefined `HandleException` method.

Should the scope of the redefined `HandleException` method be only in the units that include `ADLDebug`? I was thinking that it should be application wide, but I can't seem to call it.

Comment: It could be that the exception handler passes some (default) exceptions on to that of the application's, in which case you will not "see" the special handler in action. Though, stepping through the call stack will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of Application.OnException is indeed application wide. The event will fire whenever an exception is raised that is not handled.

You are failing to see the event fire because you are raising the exception at startup, before the message loop starts.

Comment: @peldaul: Simply raise any exception you want in the context of the main thread and let it pass into the RTL without you catching it.  For example, raising an uncaught exception in the `OnClick` event of a `TButton`.

Comment: I create a "raise exception" in my application, Delphi asks me if I want to Break or Continue.

If I select Break the debugger puts me on the line where the raise was issued.

If I then hit F8 once it takes me to the end of the procedure.

If I hit it once more it takes me into some assembly code in the middle of _HandleFinally in System.pas.

Comment: I'm expecting it to put me into either the HandleException method in Vcl.Forms.TApplication or into the newly defined ADLHandleException method. Why is it sending me to _HandleFinally?

Comment: Because finally blocks always execute. Even if you did not write finally, the compiler will do so for local variables of managed types.

Comment: Stepping through the call stack, I eventually reach some assembly code under System._ExceptionHandler. I suppose that means that the redefined exception handler is not getting used. Even if I add a TApplicationEvents component to main and add the new exception handler to it's OnException event, when clicking through the debugger I still end up at System._ExceptionHandler. Why isn't the new handler being called?

Comment: Stop stepping. Set a breakpoint in your event handler. See if it fires. If not, then perhaps you could tell us where you raise the exception and how you raise it. We cannot see your code and can merely guess at what it does.

Comment: Thank you. It does not fire. I raise the exception in the .dpr file after the uses clause after begin but before any other code. I raise the exception with the line: raise Exception.Create('Hello');

Comment: That's too early. You need to have started the message loop. So raise the exception in an OnClick handler of a button.